# Differentiability in the origin of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2\sin{y^2}}{x^2+y^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I am looking for a verification of my solution to this problem. I have to determine whether $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2\sin{y^2}}{x^2+y^4} \quad &(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\\0 &(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$ is continuous and differentiable in the origin.

So first observe $|f(x,y)|=|\frac{x^2\sin{y^2}}{x^2+y^4}|\leq|\frac{\sin{y^2}}{1+y^4/x^2}|\leq|\sin{y^2}|\to0$ as $(x,y)\to0$, so that $f$ is continuous at the origin.

Next, it is easy to show that $f_x(0,0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac0t=0$ and likewise $f_y(0,0)=0$. So clearly the candidate for the total derivative would be $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

So the limit I want to calculate is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}$ and if we calculate for $x\neq0$ $$\left|\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}\right|=\left|\frac{x^2\sin(y^2)}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|,$$ we observe that this last fraction is homogeneous to degree $1$, thus this fraction and therefore $\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}$ go to $0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. Thus $f$ is indeed differentiable in the origin and the total derivative is given by $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

My question: am I right in these claims? When I enter $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2\sin(y^2)}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ into Mathematica, the output is the same as the input. This made me doubt and I'm not sure about the total differentibality, also since other results did not apply here, e.g. the partial derivatives do not seem continuous in the origin (I know this is only a sufficient and not a necessary condition). Also, does anyone know why Mathematica does not yield the right output (either the limit value or 'indeterminate') in this case? For example when I enter $y$ without a square in the limit in Mathematica I do get 'indeterminate'.

Comment: I'm not sure for example take $x = 0$ and $ y \to 0$

Comment: $x=0$ and $y\to0$ where exactly? Which limit?

Comment: in order f to be differential you need that for any path of (x,y) to (0,0) f will go to 0 itself.

Comment: you assumed that $x$ not equal 0 by deviding in $x^2$ and thats the problem

Comment: Homogeneous of degree 1 + bounded on the unit circle gives it, not just homogeneity.

Comment: Yes, but when $x=0$ the expression equals $0$ so clearly the limit is $0$ in that case, right?

Comment: @zhw. from the function being continuous on the unit circle we can derive the boundedness, right? Because the unit circle is a compact set

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov, not neccessarily - you have to make sure that for any path for $(x_n, y_n)$ you take that its limit converges to $0$. Maybe there is a certain combination of x and y, so the function stays constant - thus not approaching 0 at all.

Comment: We can use a theorem proven in my syllabus saying that if a function is homogeneous to degree $\alpha>0$, continuous and not constant, then $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ equals $0$. All conditions seem to be satisfied here. Is the function differentiable in the origin or not?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but it should be explained.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine. I wouldn't have used homogeneity, but that argument works as long as the function is bounded on the unit circle, which is true here (although it should be explained). I would have used

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}= \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^4)}\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} \le 1\cdot \frac{x^2 +y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} = (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \to 0.$$

Comment: You're method is more direct than the homogeneity approach. I will try not to use the homogeneity when it is not necessary. The comments made me doubt even more so thanks for the verification! :)